# VB.NET Choosing specific nested class from string data

Tags: vb.net, nested-class

sorry if this is erratic as I am super new to programming. I have been searching for help on this but I am unsure what exactly I am missing and looking for.

I have edited this to try and explain the end goal.

The player has two armies, each army has five squads and each squad has five soldiers.
Each soldier has a name, level, health and xp which needs to be loaded from the database and into the correct class.

Currently I have it setup as nested classes Army#.Squad#.Soldier#.Property

From the database I can call cells that hold which army > squad > soldier the database row relates to.

What I am trying to do is populate from the database with a loop because there are hundreds of possible combinations.

```
V1 = Cell1
V2 = Cell2
V2 = Cell3
V4 = Cell4
V1.V2.V3.Health = V4
```

Comment: You might add some code to illustrate what *you* mean by nested class.  It is possible that inheritance would work better in some cases.   I generallyleave that sort of thing to the Parent Class to decide, I would rarely inflict something like `Dim myThing As New Galaxy.CluserB.TrinaryX` on myself.

Comment: How is this related to MS Access?

Comment: What version of VB .Net is this?  You probably don't need to specify the getters/setters nor the backing variables.

Comment: @JeremyCook Apologies, the database was created within access, I thought it may be relevant.

I am using VS2010 

I have since been told that I should probably scrap this and just use arrays.

Comment: Arrays are almost certainly not the answer.  The problem is that we dont know enough about the details to provide an answer and the scope is pretty large.  I suspect ClusterA is not **totally different** from ClusterB, therefore inheritance might be (part of) the answer:  A Cluster base class would have all the props and code common to all Cluster types.  Each cluster class then inherits that code and adds a small bit extra to handle whatever makes it special/different.  If you pose that question and details about those differences, you might get an answer that also applies to Trinary

Comment: @Plutonix This is a play by mail game where a database is passed from the player to the game master. 
The player has two armies, each army has five squads and each squad has five soldiers.
Each soldier has a name, level, health and xp which needs to be loaded from the database and into the correct class.

Currently I have it setup as nested classes Army#.Squad#.Soldier#.Property

Comment: I think you need multiple instances, not multiple classes.  A squad is a squad, so Army might have a List(of Squad) it maintains, but there (likely) only needs to be one Squad class.  What is in each of the 5 Squad **instances** may be very different, but that does not mean you need 5 CLASSES.  Same with Soldier - one Class with different props which indicate HP, XP, Type, Weapon etc.

Comment: @Plutonix I have created one Class for each galaxy/cluster/solder, it is the populating the correct instance of each object. I have edited my original question with what I hope is easier to understand. I am looking into the List(of T) command now to see if it may help.
Again, thank you for trying to help me even if I am stumbling blindly through this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indexed properties are going to be the closest to what you want.

```
Class Army
    Private _Squads(5) As Squad

    Property Squad( ByVal index as Integer ) As Squad
        Get
            Return _Squads( index )
        End Get

        Set( Byval this as Squad )
            _Squads( index ) = this
        End Set
    End Property

    'More
End Class

Class Squad
    Private _Units( 5 ) As Unit

    Property Unit( ByVal index as Integer ) As Unit
        'Same, but use _Units
    End Property
End Class

Class Unit

End Class
```

Which you could then do the following

```
Dim x As New Army
x.Squads( 1 ) = New Squad( )
x.Squads( 1 ).Units( 1 ) = New Unit
```

Unit could also be an Interface, or could just be a class that all of your units inherit from if you have things like swordsman, dragon, soldier, robot, or other unit types.

I haven't tested it, but it should give you an idea of one approach.

Comment: Thanks for this, it is very close to what I had but did not realize you could index properties.

I have tested it and it works perfectly for what I am trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are confusing instances and classes.  You probably do not need 5 Squad **Classes**, but likely just need 5 **Instances**.  Consider:

```
Friend Class Army
     ' an army is made up of 5 squads, so we need 
     ' 5 runtime instances of the Squad Class (lists are like arrays)
     Private squadList As New List(of Squad)

     ' identifier is something the code uses to 
     ' know which to add.  Maybe it is the SquadID from teh DB or name
     ' hard to tell
     Public Sub AddSquad(Identifier As Integer)
         ' create a new Squad instance
         Dim sq As New Squad(maybe some ID)
         ' add new squad to the LIST we are using   
         squadList.Add(sq)
     End Sub        

     Public Sub RemoveSquad(name As String)
        ' a squad died in battle; find them and remove them

        squadList.Remove(indexOfSquadnamed)
        ' now there are only 4
     End Sub

End Class
```

The "smarts" to construct Squad would be in the Squad Class. You might have one method to load the squad from the DB based on the ID, another to save the squad to the DB at the end of a turn etc.  You'd call this in a loop from Army so it saves or loads each squad it currently has.

Even if SquadB is different from SquadA, that can probably be handled by properties and/or as a result of the `List(of Soldier)` of which it is comprised.

This is all an abstract example.  Army would probably never remove a Squad from the List, but mark it as `Active = False` so that at the end of the turn, dead ones are removed, new ones are added.

Comment: I will try this code out so I understand how it works and can add it to my arsenal.
Thank you for the help.